# Dialog.setOnShowListener() alternative for API level < 8

Tags: android, android-dialog, android-dialogfragment

I have an `AlertDialog` implemented via `DialogFragment.onCreateDialog()`. The dialog has an `EditText` and two buttons, OK and Cancel. When the OK button is clicked I need to do some checking on the content of the `EditText`: if the content is wrong the dialog shouldn't be dismissed. Searching on SO I've seen that this functionality can be easily achieved this way:

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(AD_LAYOUT, null);
    mEditText = (EditText) view.findViewById(AD_VIEW);
    myAlertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
    .setView(view)
    .setTitle(getResources().getString(AD_TITLE))
    .setPositiveButton(getResources().getString(AD_PB),
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int buttonID) {
            //Do nothing. We are going to override this method
        }
    })
    .setNegativeButton(getResources().getString(AD_NB),
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int buttonID) {
            ((MainActivity)getActivity()).doNegative(NewGalleryDlg.this);
        }
    })
    .create();
    ad = myAlertDlg;

    ad.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
        @Override
        public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {
            Button b = ad.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
            b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                @Override public void onClick(View view) {
                    ((MainActivity)getActivity())
                    .doPositive(NewGalleryDlg.this, mEditText);
                }
            });
        }
    });
    return ad;
}
```

The problem is that I'm using the Support Library v4 but the `setOnShowListener()` requires API level 8 or higher. Could someone give me an alternative? TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, finally I solved it using a different approach. Instead of using `AlertDialog.setOnShowListener()` (which works fine if API level > 7) I've added a validator to the `EditText` of my `AlertDialog`. If the entered text is invalid then the OK button gets disabled.

The implementation steps are:

- make the activity to implement the `TextWatcher` interface
- the `afterTextChanged()` contains the code that does the validation and enable/disable the OK button
- in the `DialogFragment.onCreateDialog()` add the TextChanged listener to the EditText (see below)

That's all. It works like a charm now.

```
mEditText.addTextChangedListener((MainActivity)getActivity());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to inflate the particular activity which has the layout(designed using edittext , buttons and any other widgets ) as a Theme dialog in the manifest file

Answer (score 0):

What if you get the button using `findViewById()` and set an `onClickListener` for it directly? You might not need an `onShowListener` if that works.

Comment: I'm trying to do it. The problem is that the onClickListener has to be set after the dialog has been created AND showed. I simply don't know where to insert the code suggested by you, My best option was to add it in my activity, immediately after the call to show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "dialog") but it fails.

Comment: What happens if you add it before? Does it give you an error?

Comment: Yes, I'm not able to find the button because I can't get a reference to the AlertDialog instance. So something like ad.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE) raises a NullPointerException.

Comment: What about `view.findViewById(your_button_id);`?

Comment: Actually, why aren't you just doing it where you call `setPositiveButton()`? Do you even need another button?

Comment: Just because it doesn't work. There are several threads on SO explaining that when you click any button on an AlertDialog the dialog is always dismissed. If you want to change this behavior it seems that the best way to proceed is with code similar to that included in the question (please, note that I can be wrong at this point. After all I'm not an master android developer).